# Ovalbox problem in corners, no smooth

Tags: rounded-corners, box, fbox, smooth

I am using this command to make oval boxes:

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\newcommand\codeBox[1]{
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.01pt}
        \begin{center}
            \ovalbox{
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                    \textit{#1}
                \end{minipage}
            }
        \end{center}
    }
```

This is the result I have:

```
\codeBox{searchfilter="(cn="+user+")"}
```

[image]

Why aren't the corners smooth?

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. Then it is a lot easier for others to test your code. For example where does `\ovalbox` come from? And why aren't you using the `tcolorbox` package for a much more modern approach

Comment: I edited the question. I came first to ovalbox and I tried it first, not particular reason to not use tcolorbox

Comment: This is still not something others can test without having to guess 75% of your document. Please post something that others can copy and test as is. My guess: rounding errors in your previewer. If I zoom in in mine, there is no gap

Comment: The box already has smooth corners, what you see is just a PDF viewer artifact. If you zoom at a different level you will see these artifacts disappear, also they don't appear in print.